# Calculate two's complement checksum of hexadecimal string

Tags: c#, twos-complement

I have a string "0AAE0000463130004144430000" and I need to calculate the two's complement checksum of the hex bytes that make up the string.

The formula for the example string above is

1. Sum the values: 0A + AE + 00 + 00 + 46 + 31 + 30 + 00 + 41 + 44 + 43 + 00 + 00 = 27 (discard the overflow)
2. Subtract the result from 0x100 = 0xD9

D9 is the correct checksum for this example, but I am having trouble getting the two digit hex values parsed out of the string in C#.  My current code is below:

```
string output = "0AAE0000463130004144430000";
long checksum = 0;
char[] outputBytes = output.TrimStart(':').ToCharArray();

foreach (var outputByte in outputBytes)
{
    checksum += Convert.ToInt32(outputByte);
    checksum = checksum & 0xFF;
}

checksum = 256 - checksum;
```

However, this is summing the ASCII values as far as I can tell, and doing it for each individual character.

Comment: Well, you are going through each character in the string - you are not converting each pair to its byte representation first.

Comment: If I switch to byte[] outputBytes = GetBytes(output.TrimStart(':')); I still get the same (incorrect) value.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use `SoapHexBinary` class  in System.Runtime.Remoting.Metadata.W3cXsd2001.

`soapHexBinary.Value` property will return you a byte array

```
string hexString = "0AAE0000463130004144430000";
byte[] buf = SoapHexBinary.Parse(hexString).Value;

int chkSum = buf.Aggregate(0, (s, b) => s += b) & 0xff;
chkSum = (0x100 - chkSum) & 0xff;

var str = chkSum.ToString("X2"); // <-- D9
```

Comment: Why didn't I immediately look in the trusty System.Runtime.Remoting.Metadata.W3cXsd2001 namespace?  :)

Comment: You can use Convert.ToInt32(), just add "0x" to your hex strings and Convert will recognize data as hex number with no problem.

Comment: @Kamil try it with `0x123456781234567812345678`  which is large enough not to fit to an int(or long)

Comment: @L.B right, i thought thats trivial question and problem is hex format in string. Sorry.

Answer (score 2):

Try this instead. Grab two characters at a time using SubString, and read the pair of characters as a hex value using int.Parse with NumberStyles.AllowHexSpecifier.

```
string output = "0AAE0000463130004144430000";
int checksum = 0;

// You'll need to add error checking that the string only contains [0-9A-F], 
// is an even number of characters, etc.
for(int i = 0; i < output.length; i+=2)
{
   int value = int.Parse(output.SubString(i, 2), NumberStyles.AllowHexSpecifier);
   checksum = (checksum + value) & 0xFF;
}

checksum = 256 - checksum;
```

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer works if you want to include the `System.Runtime.Remoting.Metadata.W3cXsd2001` namespace.

If you do not want to include the namespace, the following code will return the correct results. The difference between this example and the example above is the additional `& 0xFF` added to the return value. Without this, you will incorrect results when calculating the checksum against all zeros.

```
public static class ExtensionMethods
{
    public static string MicrochipDataString(this string input)
    {
        int TwosComplement(string s)
        {
            if (s.Length % 2 != 0)
                throw new FormatException(nameof(input));

            var checksum = 0;

            for (var i = 0; i < s.Length; i += 2)
            {
                var value = int.Parse(s.Substring(i, 2), NumberStyles.AllowHexSpecifier);

                checksum = (checksum + value) & 0xFF;
            }

            return 256 - checksum & 0xFF;
        }

        return string.Concat(":", input, TwosComplement(input).ToString("X2"));
    }
}
```