# expressing hex value in 2's complement

Tags: c#, bit-manipulation

i have a string hex value, and i need to express it in 2's complement.

```
string hx = "FF00";
```

what i did is, converting it to binary:

```
 string h = Convert.ToString(Convert.ToInt32(hx, 16), 2 );
```

then inverting it, but i couldn't use the `NOT` operator.

is there any short way to invert the bits and then adding 1 (2's complement operation)?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12942904/calculate-twos-complement-checksum-of-hexadecimal-string

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The answer might depend on whether or not the bit width of the value is important to you.

The short answer is:

```
string hx = "FF00";
uint intVal = Convert.ToUInt32(hx, 16);      // intVal == 65280
uint twosComp = ~v + 1;                      // twosComp == 4294902016
string h = string.Format("{0:X}", twosComp); // h == "FFFF0100"
```

The value of `h` is then "FFFF0100" which is the 32-bit 2's complement of hx.  If you were expecting '100' then you need to use 16-bit calculations:

```
string hx = "FF00";
ushort intVal = Convert.ToUInt16(hx, 16);    // intVal = 65280
ushort twosComp = (ushort)(~v + 1);          // twosComp = 256
string h = string.Format("{0:X}", twosComp); // h = "100"
```

Bear in mind that `uint` is an alias for `UInt32` and `ushort` aliases the `UInt16` type.  For clarity in this type of operation you'd probably be better off using the explicit names.

Comment: Thanks Corey.. it was exactly what i was looking for.

Comment: is `v` supposed to be `intVal`? @Corey

Comment: @Nullify yeah, looks like. Close to 10 years ago, so I won't claim to know what I was thinking at the time :P

Answer (score 5):

Two complment is really simple:

```
int value = 100;

value = ~value // NOT
value = value + 1;

//Now value is -100
```

Remember that a two complement system requires inverting and adding plus 1.

In hex:

```
int value = 0x45;

value = ~value // NOT
value = value + 1;
```

Comment: what if the value is in hex? do i need to convert to `int`?

Comment: Change the literal to hex, not seeing the problem.

Comment: @Liban Is converting the string to its representation a problem?