# How to calculate the 2's Compliment of a decimal or Hex number?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

How to calculate the 2's Compliment of a decimal or Hex number  in C#, In BCL is there any inbuilt function is available,  I have something but not working ,what is the wrong with the given code

```
var number = 3092;
var onceC = ~number;
var twoC = onceC + 1;
```

Comment: Check this [Link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14929072/expressing-hex-value-in-2s-complement)

Comment: what do you mean by not working?

Answer (score 0):

Signed integer types are already using two's complement to represent negative numbers, you don't need to do anything to them.

If you display a negative number in hex format, you see the two's complement in action:

```
int number = -3092;
Console.WriteLine(number.ToString("x"));
```

Output:

```
fffff3ec
```

If you want to convert a positive number to a negative number, which makes it use two's complement, use the `-` negation operator:

```
number = -number;
```